# Como rotar imagen capturada con la cámara android

Tags: android, android-studio, app

estoy desarrollando una aplicación donde necesito crear un perfil de usuario con una imagen y un nombre, hasta ahora todo funciona correctamente menos la orientación de las fotos capturadas con el teléfono posicionado de manera vertical, en este caso la imagen recién capturada se ve rotada 90 grados, por mas que he intentado aun no la logro rotar para que se muestre tal cual como yo la capturé.

Adjunto un par de fotos para que se entienda mejor.

Esta es la imagen capturada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así es como se ve en la aplicación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button btn;
private ImageView imageview;
private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY = "/demonuts";
private int GALLERY = 1, CAMERA = 2;
private final int MY_PERMISSIONS = 100;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
            MY_PERMISSIONS);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showPictureDialog();
        }
    });

}


private void showPictureDialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder pictureDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    pictureDialog.setTitle("Select Action");
    String[] pictureDialogItems = {
            "Select photo from gallery",
            "Capture photo from camera" };
    pictureDialog.setItems(pictureDialogItems,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which) {
                        case 0:
                            choosePhotoFromGallary();
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            takePhotoFromCamera();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
    pictureDialog.show();
}

public void choosePhotoFromGallary() {
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY);
}

private void takePhotoFromCamera() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == this.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        return;
    }
    if (requestCode == GALLERY) {
        if (data != null) {
            Uri contentURI = data.getData();
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), contentURI);
                String path = saveImage(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    } else if (requestCode == CAMERA) {
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageview.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
        saveImage(thumbnail);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}



public String saveImage(Bitmap myBitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
    File wallpaperDirectory = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + IMAGE_DIRECTORY);
    // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
    if (!wallpaperDirectory.exists()) {
        wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
    }

    try {
        File f = new File(wallpaperDirectory, Calendar.getInstance()
                .getTimeInMillis() + ".jpg");
        f.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                new String[]{f.getPath()},
                new String[]{"image/jpeg"}, null);
        fo.close();
        Log.d("TAG", "File Saved::--->" + f.getAbsolutePath());

        return f.getAbsolutePath();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}


}
```

Espero alguien me pueda dar alguna idea de como solucionar este problema, desde ya muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: Checa esto, es tu problema... https://stackoverflow.com/a/41281988/5854328

Answer (score 0):

Use [ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) for rotate

```
picturePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("path");
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(picturePath);
int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
switch (orientation) {
case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
    matrix.postRotate(90);
    break;
case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
    matrix.postRotate(180);
    break;
case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
    matrix.postRotate(270);
    break;
default:
    break;
}

myImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
bitmap.recycle();
```

**Note :** Here `picturePath` is selected *Image's* path from `Gallery`

- [***tutorial***](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.media.ExifInterface)